# gfortran: fatal error: -fuse-linker-plugin, but cyglto_plugin.dll not found

Tags: eclipse, dll, fortran, cygwin, gfortran

I downloaded Eclipse and Cygwin for windows 7 64 bit. I wrote the next Fortran program:

```
program main
    print*, 'Hello World'
end program main
```

and got the next error when I tried to build the program:

```
make all 
Building target: examples
Invoking: GNU Fortran Linker
gfortran  -o "examples"  ./main.o   
gfortran: fatal error: -fuse-linker-plugin, but cyglto_plugin.dll not found
compilation terminated.
makefile:29: recipe for target 'examples' failed
make: *** [examples] Error 1
```

I looked for the file cyglto_plugin.dll, and found it in the folder:

```
C:\cygwin64\lib\gcc\x86_64-pc-cygwin\4.9.3
```

I tried to add this folder to the PATH environment variable but still got the same error.

Anyone has an idea what I can do to fix the problem?

Comment: What does a simple `gfortran -o main main.f90` give?

Comment: I'm not using eclipse, but typing at the command line I get the same error message.